# Jquery: + isn't working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am making a calculator for fun, but for some reason everything works but the addition.
Instead of adding two numbers, it is writing them both. For example 5 + 7 shows as being 57.

As I said before, -, /, and * are working fine. How should I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
$('.solve2').click(function(){
var num1 = $('#num').val();
var num2 = $('#number').val();
var ans = num1+num2;
alert(''+ans+'');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.solve2').click(function(){
var num1 = parseInt($('#num').val());
var num2 = parseInt($('#number').val());
var ans = num1+num2;
alert(''+ans+'');
});
```

Instead of parseInt, you can use parseFloat as stated in another answer.

EDIT:
As stated in the comments below, it's better to force the string to be interpreted as a decimal number. You can do this by adding the radix parameter.

```
var radix = 10; //decimal
var num1 = parseInt($('#num').val(), radix);
var num2 = parseInt($('#number').val(), radix);
```

Comment: You're missing the `radix` parameter for `parseInt`.

Comment: The radix parameter is optional,and as far as I know, the questioner does only use decimal numbers. (In the older browsers, this could be a problem when a user enters a number with a leading '0', so it might be safer to add a radix of 10. But it's not necessary.)

Comment: @Tom Octal notation is still valid and supported in modern browsers beyond strict mode.

Comment: That's not the point though. The radix is there to prevent the number being interpreted as anything but a decimal. It's entirely possible there could be a leading 0 in the input, since the values coming from the fields are strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), it Parses a string argument and returns a floating point number.

```
var ans = parseFloat(num1)+parseFloat(num2);
```

As per your example it was working as cocantenation operator

Answer (score 0):

Convert your values from strings to numbers.  The `+` is both the addition operator and cocantenation operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you must cast your string to integer. Use parseInt

```
var num1 = parseInt($('#num').val());
var num2 = parseInt($('#number').val());
```

view my sample:
[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/HU5jK/)

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value of an input element - either via plain JS or using jQuery's `.val()` - it returns as a string. And when one of the operands of `+` is a string and the other is a primitive - i.e. a number, string, boolean, `undefined` or `null` - then the other one is converted to a string and they are concatenated:

```
4 + " four" === "4 four";  // true
false + " is now a string" === "false is now a string";  // true
```

etc.

Therefore, your values returned from `.val()` are being concatenated, and you need to convert the strings returned from `.val()` into numbers using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
$('.solve2').click(function(){
    var num1 = parseFloat($('#num').val()),
        num2 = parseFloat($('#number').val()),
        ans = num1 + num2;
    console.log(ans);
});
```